# Replace the first tab with an active one (swap the tabs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to swap the first tab with an active one on click?

I have a simple Bootstrap tabs and broke my head trying to replace the first tab with an active one.

So that when I clicked on tab "D" it swaps places with tab "A".

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>bootstrap 4 vertical tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#A" role="tab" aria-controls="A">A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#B" role="tab" aria-controls="B">B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#C" role="tab" aria-controls="C">C</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#D" role="tab" aria-controls="D">D</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="A" role="tabpanel">A Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="B" role="tabpanel">B Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="C" role="tabpanel">C Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="D" role="tabpanel">D Content</div>
</div>


</div>
```

My current JS knowledge is temporarily poor so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `prependTo()` to move the clicked tab to the first position in the list. You can see this working in the example below. I would *strongly* suggest you do not do this, as it's incredibly annoying behaviour and not clear to your users why tabs are moving around.

```js
let $navlinks = $('.nav-link').on('click', e => {
  $navlinks.removeClass('active');
  $(e.target).prependTo('ul.nav');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>bootstrap 4 vertical tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#A" role="tab" aria-controls="A">A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#B" role="tab" aria-controls="B">B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#C" role="tab" aria-controls="C">C</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#D" role="tab" aria-controls="D">D</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="A" role="tabpanel">A Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="B" role="tabpanel">B Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="C" role="tabpanel">C Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="D" role="tabpanel">D Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```